# WCF runtime error [.net framework version related]

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

It's been i while that i was having a bad time hosting an iis service in a remote machine , but i got everything rigth . Well after configuring my service , i got a runtime error . The error message is : "Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Protobuf' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"
I tried changing target framework version in the application pool it threw a nice 500 error page on me . I also tried to change the .net version not only in the application pool but in my project . 
Sorry for the long data ..
**EDIT : ** I opened cmd and ran this : "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i" and everything worked correctly !

Here is my config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="ServiceGestion.Service">
<endpoint address="http://jingling.cloudapp.net/Services/Service.svc"                    binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceGestion.IService">
<identity>
<dns value="jingling.cloudapp.net" />
</identity>
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"   contract="IMetadataExchange" />
<host>
<baseAddresses>
 <add baseAddress="http://jingling.cloudapp.net/Services/" />
 </baseAddresses>
 </host>
 </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>

 </configuration>
```

Here's the stack trace :

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Protobuf'      or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase,  Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,  Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +416
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +166
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String  assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +190

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly  'Google.Protobuf' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11326360
      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +388
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +232
System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +48
 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +210
System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +191
 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +54
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +295
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +476
 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +116
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String virtualPath) +39
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String normalizedVirtualPath) +202
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +33
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +46
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +654

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Services/Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Protobuf' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded..]
System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +15778272
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +15698617
 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +265
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +227
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

Comment: check framework version from Project to deployment.

Comment: The probleme was from the .net framework installed on the server , i've edited my post .